# Angular2: How to use a (event) attribute in a parent view when the child component is added with an attribute selector

Tags: html, angular

I have a stockTakeDetail component which is used on a tr tag as a table row... i'm using the component with the [componentName] attribute selector on the table row,  the stockTakeDetail component emits a removeItem value when a button is clicked which i'm not sure at all how to register that event with the it's parent component...  Normally I would do something like this:

```
<stockTakeDetail (removeItem)="removeItem($event)"></stockTakeDetail>
```

In my parent component I have the following code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stockTakeDetailItem of stockTakeDetailList" [stockTakeDetail]="stockTakeDetailItem"></tr>
```

Any idea how I could add the event on my parent html tr?  Or is there a way to get the event directly in the parent's controller?

my code:

```
stock-take-detail.html:

<td>{{stockTakeDetail.ProductDetail_Name</td>
<td>{{stockTakeDetail.Qty}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-xs" (click)="removeCaptureItem({{stockTakeDetail.IDKey}})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>

stock-take-detail.ts:

import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { StockTakeDetailModel } from '../../models/stock-take-detail.model';

@Component({
  selector: '[stockTakeDetail]',
  templateUrl: './stock-take-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-take-detail.component.css']
})
export class StockTakeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() stockTakeDetail: StockTakeDetailModel;
    @Output() removeItem = new EventEmitter<string>();


    removeCaptureItem(iDKey: string) {      
        this.removeItem.emit()
    }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


table from stock-take.html:

<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Desc</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>       
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--<tr *ngFor="let stockTakeDetailItem of stockTakeDetailList" [stockTakeDeTail]="stockTakeDetailItem"></tr>-->
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: you can use Event Emitter and emit this event so parent can use it

Comment: @Yashveer Singh I am doing that...  think you might be misunderstanding

Comment: ok can you please share your component.ts for details component and template of the parent please

Comment: @Yashveer Singh I just added code.  Thanks for taking a look...

Comment: please share parent component template where you are using

Comment: @Yashveer Singh  it's used on the table at the bottom...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133438/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-user2094257).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help; parent has an EventEmitter, you pass it into the children in the ngFor. Any of the children that use that emitter to emit an event, all the other children will hear it if you want (they just subscribe), and the parent will hear any component that uses its emitter to emit an event (e.g. the children) if you subscribe. Very easy, works great.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let btn of buttons">
    // Bind the parent's broadcast listener, to the child Input.
    <my-child [broadcastListener]="broadcasterParent">
    </my-child>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Parent:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
  ...
  constructor  ) {
  // this is the instance given to the child as Input
  this.broadcasterParent = new EventEmitter ( );
  // Note if you want the parent to hear the event,
  // subscribe to the event emitter, just like the children do. 
  this.broadcastListener.subscribe( ( b ) => this.onBroadcast ( b ) );

}

onBroadcast ( evt ) {
   ... you will hear when the child emits an event using the emitter
}
```

Child:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor ( ) {
  // This is almost certainly better used in OnInit.
  // It is how the child subscribes to the parent's event emitter.
  // You only need to do this if you want to hear events.
  this.broadcastListener.subscribe( ( b ) => this.onBroadcast ( b ) );
}

onButtonClick ( evt ) {
  // Any component anywhere that has subscribed 
  // to this emitter will hear this event, e.g. the parent or whatever
  // andwill hear it
  this.broadcastListener.emit ( evt );
}

// Only needed if the child subscribed to the parent's emitter
onBroadcast ( evt ) {
  // This will be the data that was sent by whatever button was clicked
  // via the subscription to the Input event emitter (parent, app, etc).
  console.log ( evt );
}

ChildComponent.annotations = [
  new Component ( {
    ... // TS would use an attribute for this
    inputs: [ 'broadcastListener' ]
    template: `
      <div click)="onButtonClick ( $event )">
      ...
      </div>
    `
  })
];
```

Explained in more detail here: (Peer Events in Angular 2):

www.tcoz.com/#/errata

Comment: Note there is a future-state recommendation that EventEmitter may change, so you may want to use Subject. Personally, I'll worry about that when it actually happens, there are tons of samples using EventEmitter, but for completeness I figured I'd mention it.